# Foreach Loop ADO Enumerator With a Dynamic/Changing Table

Tags: sql-server, foreach, ssis

I am running a Foreach Loop using an ADO Enumerator.  It's pretty straight forward...a sql task that gathers all distinct Filed1 records from Table1...loads an object variable with the full result set...then it kicks off a long fun process within a loop...when that Field1 value is done processing it deletes that value from the table...so now there are 14...when the loop is done the table is empty.  It works great only I would like it to look for new Field1 records from Table1 when it is done processing the initial Field1 values.  For example if Table1 had 15 distinct Field1 values...I then insert 10 more distinct Field1 values after the loop has started but is still executing...I want it to recognize/look for those 10 additional records and kick off the loop again.  Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a foreach, use a For Loop Container, and keep running the process until the query that loads the object variable doesn't return any rows.